# Google Merchant Center: Unable to link business profile

Tags: google, google-my-business

##### What is the issue?

We are using Google Merchant Center and are unable to link out business profile to MCA. We had a merchant center account in the past, that was deleted to start over fresh. Somehow MCA still thinks that the business profile is linked to the old account and I am unable to connect it again.

[image]

##### Resolution steps taken

- I have tried to talk to Google Support without success, Google Business Profile Support tells me I need to talk to MCA Support and vice versa, they wasted my time for 2 days straight.
- There is not really anything on the web, not even a blog post of someone that has the same issue. Google Cloud does not offer an API that may help my cause.